# What is wrong with my code when i press log in it redirect me to log in page?

Tags: php, session

i don't know what is wrong with my code when there is no  members page the log in redirect me to the members page address with 404 error that isn't the problem , it redirect me to login page when i log in when i write this code in members page.

```
 <?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_level'])or ($_SESSION['user_level'] != 0)){
    header('location: login.php');
exit();
}?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Admin page
    </title>
    <style>
        table{text-align: center;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
if($_SESSION['fname']){
    echo 'welcome to admin page '. $_SESSION['fname'] . "<br>";
}
?>
<input type="button" value="Log Out" onclick="window.location=' logoutt.php '">
</body>
</html>
```

login page code

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $dbcon=mysqli_connect('localhost','mahmud91','password','postaldb')or die('Couldn\'t connect to database'.mysqli_error($dbcon));
    if(!empty(trim($_POST['email']))){
        $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,trim($_POST['email']));
    }else{
        $email=false;
    }
    if(!empty(trim($_POST['psword']))){
        $psword=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,trim($_POST['psword']));
    }else{
        $psword=false;
    }if($email && $psword){
        $query="SELECT fname,user_id,user_level FROM users WHERE (email='$email' AND psword=SHA1('$psword'))";
        $result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);
        if(@mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
            $_SESSION=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $_SESSION['user_level']=(int)$_SESSION['user_level'];
            $url=($_SESSION['user_level']===1) ? "adminnpage.php" : "memberrpage.php";
            header('location: '.$url);
        }else{
            echo "Sorry no match was found to email or password";
        }
    }else{
        echo" Please try again";
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Log In
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/newfolder/login.php" method="post">
<p>
<label for="email">Email: </label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" >
</p>
<p>
<label for="psword">Password: </label>
<input type="password" name="psword" id="psword">
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In">
</p>
<p>
<input type="button" value="Register" onclick="window.location='/newfolder/registerpage.php'">
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show your login page code..

Comment: i added login page code

Comment: everything looks great just start the session..on login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to start session at the top of login page just after php tag

```
session_start();
```